# Which conferences are comparable to the Defcon?

Tags: professional-education, conference

Rory Aslop wrote something interesting regarding conferences [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17126/what-are-some-good-arguments-for-having-your-work-send-you-to-e-g-defcon-or-bla):

> Defcon always worked out as the most cost effective broad technical training for my penetration testers and technical security teams...[it] gives:
>
> - cutting edge training
> - direct experience of 'black hat' activities
> - value for money

Are there other comparable conferences (international and not necessarily in English) from an importance and content perspective?

Answer (score 3):

There are many, I searched for some of them in different forums:

1. [HITB Security Conference](http://conference.hitb.org/hitbsecconf2015ams/#tile_schedule)
2. [Black Hat](https://www.blackhat.com/) (various events and conferences every year every where)
3. [B-Sides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_Sides_%28Security_Conference%29) (much smaller but more populist conference)
4. [The Hacker Conference](https://conference.think.org/about/) (first organized in 1984)
5. [Blue Hat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlueHat) (Microsoft Hacker Conference hold twice per year)
6. [Brucon](http://2015.brucon.org/index.php/Main_Page) (conferences, training ... once a year, Belgium)
7. [TROOPERS](https://www.troopers.de/troopers/) (once per year, Germany)
8. [Growth Hacking Conference](http://www.growthhackingconference.com/) (UK)
9. [Virus Bulletin](https://www.virusbtn.com/index) (once per year, coming one by the end of September)
10. [Hack.lu](http://2015.hack.lu/) (annual,  coming one on 20-22 October 2015, Luxembourg )
11. [NDSS](https://www.internetsociety.org/events/ndss-symposium-2015) (annual, last one done on February 2015)
12. [nullcon](http://nullcon.net/website/) (once a year, last conference done on  06 - 07th Feb 2015, in Delhi and Goa, Asia)
13. [RSA Security Conference](http://www.rsaconference.com/) (annually in USA)
14. [SecureWorld Expo](https://www.secureworldexpo.com/) (annually, USA)
15. [Hacker Halted](https://www.hackerhalted.com/2015/) (annually, placement changes every year)
16. [DeepSec](https://deepsec.net/) (annually, their conferences are always published on Youtube, Austria)
17. [Hackito Ergo Sum](http://2014.hackitoergosum.org/) (April of each year, Paris-France)
18. [ICM](http://icmconference.org/) (more about cryptography)
19. [SIN ACM](http://www.sinconf.org/sin2015/index.php) (annually, next conference on September 8-10, 2015, Russia)
20. [CanSecWest](https://cansecwest.com/) (on March of each year, Canada)
21. [ASIA](http://www.albany.edu/iasymposium/) (annual,  cyber security conference, USA)
22. [FSec](http://fsec.foi.hr/) (annual, coming conference on 14th—16th September 2015, Croatia)